# This code seems not to work why not I'm confused

Tags: python, shuffle

I'm trying to make a program where the computer randomly picks a word from a list then shuffle the letters from that word around and it's not working. Why is it not working?

```
import random
mysports= ["swimming" , "basketball" , "soccer" , "cross country" , 
"football" , "cross-country skiing"]
letters = mysports[0]
letters1 = mysports[1]
letters2 = mysports[2]
letters3 = mysports[3]
letters4 = mysports[4]
letters5 = mysports [5]
a = (random.choice(mysports)) 
if a == mysports[0]:
   b = random.shuffle(letters)
   print (b)
elif a == mysports[1]:
   c = random.shuffle(letters1)
   print (c)
elif a == mysports[2]:
   d = random.shuffle(letters2)
   print (d)
elif a == mysports[3]:
   e = random.shuffle(letters3)
   print (e)
elif a == mysports[4]:
   f = random.shuffle(letters4)
   print (f)
elif a == mysports[5]:
   g = random.shuffle(letters5)
   print (g)
```

This is what it gives me when I try to run it:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "python", line 23, in
>    TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: See the [help for `random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle): Shuffle the sequence x **in place**. It modifies the existing sequence in place; doesn't return a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

random.shuffle() can only shuffle lists. To do what you want, you must turn the letters of the word into a list.

I recommend doing this

```
import random
mysports= ["swimming" , "basketball" , "soccer" , "cross country" , 
"football" , "cross-country skiing"]
letters = mysports[0]
letters1 = mysports[1]
letters2 = mysports[2]
letters3 = mysports[3]
letters4 = mysports[4]
letters5 = mysports [5]
a = random.choice(mysports)
aList = []
for char in a:
    aList.extend(char)
random.shuffle(aList)
aString = ""
for char in aList:
    aString += char
print(aString)
```

It will do what you want and more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!! It worked this took me so much time and I couldn't get it... anyways thanks I would have never guessed doing that!

Comment: @TheCoder360 you're welcome, please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I did but I have another question. So how do I make it that I ask the user to guess what the actual word is. I printed it but with the way you did it I'm a bit confused on how to tell the user how to guess it because I have to do it for each one

Comment: @TheCoder360 Give me 20 minutes and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, are you like a professional coder? I'm at an intermediate level, but I've never tried lists before and I just started trying them.

Comment: @TheCoder360 Nope, I'm just a high school student that really like coding.

Comment: @TheCoder360 Ok, I'm done can you post a new question so that I can give it to you?

Comment: Umm ok. Sure I will

Comment: I'm sorry I can't I can only post once every 90 mins

Comment: just type it in here I won't mind

Comment: @TheCoder360 Ok, I just realized I can post a link. https://repl.it/@AaronRodriguez2/Stack-Help-1 I also changed cross-country skiing to tennis because I thought it would be easier to guess, and they share the same first 3 letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use repl.it too btw if you want to check out my calculator:https://repl.it/@OmarN/Calculator?language=python3

Comment: @TheCoder360 wow, that's cool